# Yii2 URLs with published year, month, and slug

Tags: yii2

I am creating a blog using Yii2 I would like to have the post URLs be the year, month, and slug of the post.  I have the slug currently working to validate against itself only but I am not sure how to tell the sluggable behavior to take the year and month into consideration when generating unique slugs.

In my post table I have a slug (based on post title) and published_at datetime.  I currently have the following setup which retrieves a given post based on year, month, and slug.

The urlManager has `'/<year:\d{4}>/<month:\d{2}>/<slug>' => 'post/view',` and in my controller is the following:

```
public function actionView($year, $month, $slug)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($year, $month, $slug);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
...
protected function findModel($year, $month, $slug)
{
    $model = Post::find()
        ->where(['slug' => $slug])
        ->andWhere(['FROM_UNIXTIME(publish_at, "%m")' => $month])
        ->andWhere(['FROM_UNIXTIME(publish_at, "%Y")' => $year])
        ->one();
    if ($model !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested post does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Currently, the Post model only defines the following behavior.

```
'SluggableBehavior' => [
    'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
    'attribute' => 'title',
    'immutable' => true,
    'ensureUnique' => true,
],
```

How can I edit the behavior so that in evaluates the year, month, and slug when determining uniqueness?

Do I perhaps needs to store the year and month in the database rather than just dynamically pulling them out of the published_at datetime (which I am currently doing during the find())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

I created columns for the year and month so that the publish_at field does not need to be evaluated on the fly.  With year and month stored in their own column, the `uniqueValidator` property is set on the SluggableBehavior as follows

```
'uniqueValidator' => ['targetAttribute' => ['publish_year', 'publish_month', 'slug']],
```

With `targetAttribute` set for `uniqueValidator`, the behavior will take all three fields into consideration when determining if the slug is unique.

## Long answer

In case anyone else wants to implement something similar, here are all the various pieces that went into making this solution work.

#### Post.php (model)

This ensures that when the slug is generated, it also uses the publish_year and publish_month fields to evaluate whether or not the slug is unique

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'SluggableBehavior' => [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => ['title'],
            'immutable' => true,
            'ensureUnique' => true,
            'uniqueValidator' => ['targetAttribute' => ['publish_year', 'publish_month', 'slug']],
        ],
    ];
}
```

The following rule is to ensure that if a user manually enters a slug, it is still evaluated against the year and month for uniqueness

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ....
        [['slug'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['publish_year', 'publish_month', 'slug'],
    ];
}
```

I allow the users to enter a date for publishing and will populate the year and month based on what they enter. The important piece to note here is that the parent implementation of beforeValidate needs to be **after** setting these values so that they are set when the sluggableBehavior executes.  If the user did not set a publish_at datetime, then the current time is used (the user can change this later but we need to make some kind of assumption about the date so that we have a year and month to check against).

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    $publish_at = ($this->publish_at) ? $this->publish_at : time();
    $this->publish_year = date('Y', $publish_at);
    $this->publish_month = date('m', $publish_at);

    // Invoke parent implementation
    parent::beforeValidate();

    return true;
}
```

#### web.php (config)

The urlManager needs the following rule to direct posts to the correction controller/action

```
'/<year:\d{4}>/<month:\d{2}>/<slug>' => 'post/view',
```

#### PostController.php (controller)

Finally, the controller needs to know what to do with this data to find the proper post

```
public function actionView($year, $month, $slug)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($year, $month, $slug);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

This is not every last line of code needed to make this function (for example, obviously findModel needs to find the proper post with that year, month, and slug rather than just the id like usual) but this should at least get someone pointed in the right direction when trying to accomplish something similar.